# I can't bring a word to beginning of the line

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

When I try to bring a word to beginning of the line it jumps to top line but I don't want it. I use tab indent instead spaces and hope I wont need to use spaces as indents.

Example:
I indicated where the cursor is with `|` character

```
class MyClass {
    int abc;
    |// comment
}
```

when I press backspace key, the line where the cursor is at jumps to top line and the new code looks like below

```
class MyClass {
    int abc;|// comment
}
```

but I want it to look like this

```
class MyClass {
    int abc;
|// comment
}
```

Comment: Intellij is going to fight you on this, since your style is essentially at odds with how the entire rest of the world writes code.  You could try disabling Intellij's auto-formatting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, In the past when I was using eclipse, I easily could do this but intellij made me angry about this. and Is it possible to do this in intellij?

Comment: Well, you're not in Eclipse anymore, are you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've just want to switch the ide I used, for android stuffs. this is a great surprise from intellij to me :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey should I break writing code like this ? and where should my comments be at ? is intellij right about that ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, intellij is right.  The comment you're proposing is associated with the ending brace; why would you put one there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Backspace Unindent behavior here:

[image: unindent]